# automate saving info from a dictionary in an excel table on a daily basis

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I have a dictionary with 10 keys – the keys remain the same but the values are updated each day.

How can I save the daily changes in the value while preserving the previous ones?

try csv in pycharm but every time i run the program it replaces the old data

Comment: here answer on your question [how-to-append-a-new-row-to-an-existing-csv-file](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-append-a-new-row-to-an-existing-csv-file/)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by using 'a' in open(). I am assuming that you had done something similar, using 'w' instead. 'a' will append to the file, meaning that the data is added instead of replaced. Here is a function that will append the data to a new row in the CSV file. You said the values are updated each day, but the keys remain the same. In the case of a single dictionary being used, this will handle each key with changing values.

```
import csv

def csv_dict_writer(path, fieldnames, data):
    with open(path, "a", newline='') as out_file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writerow(data)

data = {
    'Name': 'John Doe',
    'Age': 30,
    'Gender': 'Male',
}

path = 'path.csv'

fieldnames = data.keys()

csv_dict_writer(path, fieldnames, data)
```

Also, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) is a good place to see how the open() function works. And [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv) is a page for the csv module.